# Pushing the `dist` directory of a vue-cli project to a subfolder of an nginx server using git hooks

Tags: git, vue.js, nginx, githooks, vue-cli

I created a Vue project with vue-cli. My production code gets built to a `dist` folder locally. Currently, when I commit that code and push to its origin, there is a post-receive hook set up to deploy the contents of that `dist` folder to the root of a server - `http://site_name.com`. What I want to do is have that `dist` folder go to a subfolder of the server, `http://site_name.com/highlights`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to define a location block and specify the path to your dist folder. In your case, add this code in`sites_enabled/site_name.com.conf`:

```
location /highlights {
    root path/to/your/app/dist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a very good page on the official Vue CLI docs that goes over common deployment strategies, that has a great example nginx config which I personally use in my apps: (https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx)

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
      root   /app;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
}
```

This has been working great for me. I just copy my dist folder to a directory called `/app` on my server. I personally do this with docker, which there's a great example of on this page too.